# Changing Attachment Header MIME python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, mime

I have attempted to change the header of my attached pdf from the default "noname" to some other header. Unfortunately the following "add_header" part of my code doesn't change the actual header name. Are there any alternatives without corrupting or altering the contents of the attached file?

```
fromaddr = 'XXXXX@gmail.com'  
toaddrs  = 'XXXXX@gmail.com'

username = 'XXXX'  
password = 'XXXXX'
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject']='Spam'

msg.preamble = 'SDFSFSDF'


file=open(r'XXXXXX.pdf','rb').read()

msg.attach(MIMEApplication(file,'pdf'))

msg.add_header('XXXXXX', 'file', filename = 'XXXXXX.pdf')

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)  
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)  
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())  
time.sleep(2)
```

**EDIT**

This is the file heading that is attached:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
msg.add_header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="%s"' % 'XXXXX.pdf')
```

which would produce this header in the messsage

```
'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="XXXXX.pdf"'
```

Replacing the original `add_header` call with

```
msg.add_header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="%s"' % 'hello.pdf')
```

produces this output in the smtp debugging server<sup>*</sup>

```
b'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============3303386632460914267=="'                                                   
b'MIME-Version: 1.0'                                                                                                                
b'Subject: Spam'                                                                                                                    
b'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="hello.pdf"'                                                                            
b'X-Peer: ::1'                                                                                                                      
b''                                                                                                                                 
b'SDFSFSDF'                                                                                                                         
b'--===============3303386632460914267=='                                                                                           
b'Content-Type: application/pdf'                                                                                                    
b'MIME-Version: 1.0'                                                                                                                
b'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'                                                                                                
b''
b'LotsOfBase64'
```

---

<sup>*</sup>`python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025`

Comment: What header do you get?

Comment: "noname" is the header I get

Comment: I've added the output I get.  Perhaps you can [edit] your question to show the exact header that are generated?

Comment: I added the output of the heading when the email is sent. As you can see it still says "noname". Perhaps it has to do with updating the MIME version?